# Error: H must be the handle to a figure or figure descendent

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have three guis: gui1, gui2, and gui3. Here's how they work. Gui1 is the main gui, gui2 is called by gui1, and subsequently gui3 called by gui2. Now in the `CloseRequestFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)` of gui3 I have written the following code:

```
function settings_CloseRequestFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to settings (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hint: delete(hObject) closes the figure

saveState(handles);
h=findobj('Tag','gui2');
gdata=guidata(h);

<some code here>

delete(hObject);
```

So in gui3 I used `gdata` to access all handles of gui2. Now after I run gui1, and then using it gui2, and by the latter gui3 I don't get any error. But when tried to close gui3 I got the following error:

```
Error using guidata (line 89)
H must be the handle to a figure or figure descendent.

Error in settings_CloseRequestFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) (line 116)
gdata=guidata(h);
```

I don't know what it means. But when gui1 is closed and I open gui3 by gui2 I don't get that error and everything works fine. The problem comes when I first open the parent gui1. How to fix that issue?

Best

Comment: It likely means that `findobj` is not returning a handle. [Use the debugger](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) to see what is being returned by `findobj` when the error is generated.

Comment: The problem goes away when gui1 is closed. But when it's open and then I try to close gui3 I get the error.

Comment: Without an functional example that replicates your error we cannot help you. Use the debugger and see what changes. Have you verified that your figure window tags are correct?

Comment: oh, thank you. As you said it was due to window figure tags. It seems that I had used before the tag 'animation' somewhere in the code but again I used it to name the gui2. It now works. Thanks!

Comment: Also @excaza if the following code returns false then what do we get?                                                                                                          `if ~isempty(findobj('Tag','animation3'))`
`h=findobj('Tag','animation3');`
`gdata=guidata(h);`
`end`

Comment: It is clear that there is a thing going with `findobj`. When using that we try to find the tag of a figure which is closed we would get the above error. But when the figure is open it can easily find the tag and nothing goes bad thereafter. So isn't a better alternative to the  `findobj` function? It seems that it doesn't work when the figure it is looking for is closed.

Comment: That's correct, `findobj` will not work if the figure window is closed because the object has been deleted. For a simple fix you can use [`isempty`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isempty.html) test to see if the return of `findobj` is empty and control appropriately with an [`if` statement](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html). This means that no object could be found using the criteria you passed to `findobj`; in this case that will usually mean the figure had been closed.